# Cardinals comparison in Jones' lemma

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, separation-axioms

In Willard's General Topology, (ed. Dover, p100), the lemma 15.2 (Jones' lemma) states that:

> If $X$ contains a dense set $D$ and a closed, relatively discrete
> subspace $S$ with $|S| \ge 2^{|D|}$, then $X$ is not normal.

However, the proof leads momentarily to the condition $|P(S)|\gt|P(D)|$ that would forbid the normality, thus $|S|\gt|D|$, but this result is immediately inexplicably weakened into $|S|\ge2^{|D|}$.

But the previous form was both stronger and easier to manipulate, so why is it necessary to weaken it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $|S|>|D|$ does not imply $|P(S)|>|P(D)|$ (or at least ZFC cannot prove that it does).  For instance, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$.  On the other hand, $|S|\geq 2^{|D|}$ definitely does imply $|P(S)|>|P(D)|$ since $$|P(S)|=2^{|S|}\geq 2^{2^{|D|}}>2^{|D|}=|P(D)|$$ with the strict inequality by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: +1. To the OP, this is my favorite example of a ZFC-independence, much better than CH. "Clearly" bigger sets have bigger powersets ... nope! (Incidentally, this phenomenon happens already in the standard construction of a model of ZFC + ~CH from a model of ZFC + V=L, so it's not hard to produce, just deeply surprising at first.)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! I was not prepared to reach as far as ZFC here, so that's a very nice surprise ;)
It motivates me to spend some time to study more infinite cardinals and axiomatic sets theory!!

Comment: @almaus Under MA + not CH, there are separable normal spaces  with a closed discrete subspace of size $\aleph_1$, showing that $|S| > |D|$ alone cannot refute normality. Related to the [Normal Moore space conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)#Normal_Moore_space_conjecture) which was for some time one of the major open problems in general topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you!!